# Antlr should place some marker if there is no value provided

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr4, spaces, lexer

I have such a line to parse:

```
*A VE 8507492 8065969 1234 00922 00945                %
```

All of those values are optional. This is my Grammar for it:

```
a_ve:  '*A VE' INT* INT* INT* INT* INT* PROZ;
```

where INT is:

```
INT: [0-9]+ ; and: SPACE: [\r\n ]+ -> skip:
```

Since all of those values are optional, I can end up with such a line:

```
*A VE 8507492 8065969 1234         00945                     %
```

where the value 00922 is not there. But in my abstract parse tree there is nothing for the value 00922. There should be something so I can recognize that there were no values. The spaces between all values (8507492 8065969) should be ignored. What should I changed in my grammar to achieve that?

Comment: Did you mean for those `*`s to be `?`s? Otherwise I don't see how any but the first `INT*` will ever match any tokens.

Comment: You are right. Those '*' can be replaced with '?'

Comment: Your example seems to indicate that your lines are fixed-length fields, so it is not the case that spaces should just be ignored. Otherwise, it is impossible to know *which* of the five numbers is missing in the example line. Antlr may not be the optimal tool for "parsing" fixed-length inputs.

Comment: You are correct! All fields of the line has a fixed-length value. What can be ignored is the space between 2 fields. Spaces which occurs when there is no value for a field, should not be ignored. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

From a syntactic standpoint, what makes the value `00922` stand out in a row of integers? Right, nothing. The parser (which is only matching syntax to defined rules) cannot know that this number has a special meaning for you. It's a semantic problem you have to solve after parsing. The entire rule should just be:

```
a_ve: '*A VE' INT* PROZ;
```

Then in your parse tree (note: there is no such thing like an **abstract** parse tree) you can check the incoming numbers and act on them. What you consider missing or not is up to you then.

Comment: Why does `a_ve: '*A VE' INT* PROZ;` produces thes same parse tree as this `a_ve:  '*A VE' INT* INT* INT* INT* INT* PROZ;`

Comment: A parse tree represents the way of the parser through the rules, to match the input. Both rules obviously cause the parser to take the same path.